# Is there a Way to bind Supplier<T> in google guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, guice-3

I tried doing that like below

```
bind(configClass).toProvider(Provider<Supplier<T>>).in(Singleton.class);
```

But I'm getting this error.

> no suitable method found for
> toProvider(com.google.inject.Provider<java.util.function.Supplier>)

Comment: You probably need to use the `TypeLiteral` signature.

Comment: Aha!! :) I'll look into that 

Thank you!! @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: What type is `configClass`?

Comment: Class<T> Class type

Comment: This is what I really wanna do 

When a Supplier<T> requested, Then I  wanna bind an instance using google guice, 
To bind an instance it reads a file and assigns those values to the respective fields in the class. 

Supplier interface is taken from guava, cuz after reading we can store the values in memory and I don't need to read the file again and again. 
With the Supplier interface, with its get method, it returns the values from its memory.

But the guice binding is still a little bit confusing to me .

@OlivierGrégoire